# Shortcode - Display inline icon before text

Tags: shortcode

i created buttons with shortcodes, and i need to add icon before the first text like this http://s32.postimg.org/codndv6s5/Bez_n_zvu.jpg

here is the shortcode

```
[button iconurl="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/wp-content/themes/cityguide/design/img/child.png"  title="Děti" description="Rozcestník pro děti a mladistvé do 15 let" marginright="0%" width="45%" iconalign="top" textalign="center" align="left" url="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/cat/deti/" bgcolor="#00968f"] [button iconurl="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/wp-content/themes/cityguide/design/img/man.png" title="Dospělí" description="Rozcestník pro dospělé" marginleft="0%" width="45%" iconalign="top" textalign="center" align="right" url="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/cat/dospeli/" bgcolor="#00968f"] [rule type="clear"]
```

and here is the site >http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal

please advise, thanks

Comment: Please share the shortcode code that you created.

Comment: No, the shortcode _code_ i.e. `add_shortcode` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shortcode is not echoing the html in the right way. You have

```
<span class="icon">
    <img ...>
</span>
<span class="text">
    <span class="title"> ... </span>
    <span class="description"> ... </span>
</span>
```

In this way you cannot put icon and title inline. You need:

```
<span class="icon-title">
    <img ...>
    <span class="title"> ... </span>
</span>
<span class="description"> ... </span>
```

This more a css thing than something that has to do with WP, by the way

i (Thomas) found this:

```
<a
    href="<?php echo esc_url($attrs->url) ?>"
    <?php if($attrs->urlnewwindow != "" and $attrs->urlnewwindow == "1" ){
        echo 'target="_blank"'; }
    ?>
    id="<?php echo $this->htmlId ?>"
    class="<?php echo $this->htmlClass, " align{$attrs->align} ", " buticon-{$attrs->iconalign} " ?> <?php if($attrs->iconurl != "") echo 'buticon' ?> <?php if(($attrs->title == "") and ($attrs->description == "")) echo 'notext' ?> <?php if(($attrs->title != "") and ($attrs->description == "") and ($attrs->iconurl == "")) echo 'simple' ?>"
    style="<?php echo $style[0], $style[1], $style[5], $style[6], $style[7], $style[8] ?>"
>
    <span class="container">
        <span class="wrap">

            <?php if($attrs->iconurl != ""){ ?>
                <?php if($attrs->iconalign == "top" or $attrs->iconalign == "left") { ?>
                <span class="icon" style="<?php echo $style[4] ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($attrs->iconurl) ?>" alt="button icon">
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php }elseif(!empty($attrs->fonticon)){ ?>
                <?php if($attrs->iconalign == "top" or $attrs->iconalign == "left") { ?>
                    <span class="icon" style="<?php echo $style[4] ?>">
                        <i class="fa <?php echo esc_attr($attrs->fonticon) ?>" <?php if(!empty($attrs->titlecolor)) { ?>style="color: <?php echo esc_attr($attrs->titlecolor) ?>;"<?php } ?>></i>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if(($attrs->title != "") or ($attrs->description != "")) { ?>
            <span class="text" style="<?php echo $style[4] ?>">
                <?php if($attrs->title != ""){ ?>
                <span class="title" style="<?php echo $style[2] ?>">
                    <?php
                    if($attrs->escapetext != "" and $attrs->escapetext == "0"){
                        echo html_entity_decode($attrs->title);
                    } else {
                        echo esc_html($attrs->title);
                    }
                    ?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($attrs->description != ""){ ?>
                <span class="description" style="<?php echo $style[3] ?>">
                    <?php
                        if($attrs->escapetext != "" and $attrs->escapetext == "0"){
                            echo html_entity_decode($attrs->description);
                        } else {
                            echo esc_html($attrs->description);
                        }
                        ?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
            </span>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if($attrs->iconurl != ""){ ?>
                <?php if($attrs->iconalign == "bottom" or $attrs->iconalign == "right") { ?>
                <span class="icon" style="<?php echo $style[4] ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($attrs->iconurl) ?>" alt="button icon">
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php }elseif(!empty($attrs->fonticon)){ ?>
                <?php if($attrs->iconalign == "bottom" or $attrs->iconalign == "right") { ?>
                    <span class="icon" style="<?php echo $style[4] ?>">
                        <i class="fa <?php echo esc_attr($attrs->fonticon) ?>" <?php if(!empty($attrs->titlecolor)) { ?>style="color: <?php echo esc_attr($attrs->titlecolor) ?>;"<?php } ?>></i>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! it possible to implement pure css to this shortcode lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here with "pure css". Do you mean adding inline css? Sure, that's possible. But it is better to put the styles in your style sheet. (if you like the answer, please accept it so this question is closed)

Comment: Yes, i mean inline css, but it try with example (display:inline-block and float: left) but not help, please advise, thank you

Comment: You should be fine if you put `float:left` on the icon and `float:right` on the title.

Comment: Ok, i spend hours for this trouble ,i try this

Comment: You have not made any changes to your site. There is nothing more to advice than I already did.

Comment: please help me to create html version of this shortcode above

Comment: You have given the shortcode itself, but not the php code that converts the shortcode into html.

Comment: hi, found it, i create a new thread?

Comment: You'll have to move the code part that starts with `<span class="title"` to above, so it will generate the html as I indicated in the answer. Remember to make a backup of the file, so you can restore everything in case you mess up. Once the html is done, apply the floats.